# mysql_error showing blank

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering why mysql_error is showing blank even though it is false.

```
mysql_select_db("ps4_austint", $con);

// Create a new resume element
iresumeq = "INSERT INTO Resume (resume_name) VALUES ('$name')";
if (!(mysql_query($iresumeq,$con))){
     die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

`Error:` 
Is being displayed.

Comment: This is funny and weird!!! :o

Comment: just a guess, double negative?, use `if (!mysql_query($iresumeq,$con)){`

Comment: Kindly add-slashes before $name and try again

Comment: @Vineet1982 Add slashes?

Comment: don't you have Unnecessary `Space`  between `.` and `mysql_error()` ?

Comment: @GilPeretz Yes, but I tried taking out the space, and it does not make a differnece.

Comment: Kindly refer to the manual for more info http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php. As to add some special characters we need addslashes function

Comment: @Vineet1982 do not use addslashes that is not safe. It will still allow SQL injection.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @crypticツ its the suggestions to check does it include special characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!(mysql_query($iresumeq,$con))){
    ^ negative operator
```

So, you're getting no error

Comment: you are right it is the negative operator showing error as there is not error in execution